# Toggle toolbar visibility in TinyMCE via menu item

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

How do I toggle the visibility of a TinyMCE toolbar via a menu item. The checkmark state of the menu item should correspond to the visibility of the toolbar. Note that I am using TinyMCE 4.1.9, which seems to no longer have a `controlManager` property.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        menu: {
            edit   : {title : 'Edit'  , items : 'undo redo'},
            view   : {title : 'View'  , items : 'visualaid secondarytoolbar'}
        },
        toolbar1: "undo redo", 
        toolbar2: "fontselect fontsizeselect",     
        setup: function(editor) {
          editor.addMenuItem('secondarytoolbar', {
              text: 'Secondary toolbar',
              selectable: true,
              context: 'view',
              onclick: function() {
                  // Toggle "toolbar2" on/off and set checkmark on menu item accordingly.
                  // ?
              }
          });
        }
     }); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on something similar but could not figure out how to get the check mark to show up. Your post cleared that part up for for me. Here is how I show/hide an additional toolbar row. You can find more info here:
http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32854

```
editor.on("BeforeRenderUI", function (e) {
    editor.theme.panel.find("toolbar").slice(1).hide();
});

editor.addMenuItem("advancedToolbar", {
    text: "Show Advanced Toolbar",
    selectable: true,
    context: "tools",
    onclick: function () {
        if (!this.active()) {
            this.active(true);
            editor.theme.panel.find("toolbar").slice(1).show();
        } else {
            this.active(false);
            editor.theme.panel.find("toolbar").slice(1).hide();
        }
    }
});
```